# How to shift a column of numbers in a DataFrame by specified time lag in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, shift

In my DataFrame, there might be missing dates (such as weekends, holidays etc.), so the dates are not strictly continuous, and the shift has to be the latest available. For example, if the date is 2023-09-08, lag is 3, while 2023-09-05 is not available, then look for 2023-09-04 and till an available number is found. I might want to shift the column by days, months and years.

```
values = range(1000)
begin_date = '2022-01-01'

df = pd.DataFrame({'value':values, 
                   'date':pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=len(values))})
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# make the dates incontinuous
df.drop(df.loc[(df['value']>40) & (df['value']<50)].index, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

I can use following:

```
df['new_value'] = df['value'].shift(3, freq='D')
```

But it relies on that the date column has to be continuous, and I cannot get freq='M'/'m' working. The error is: `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`.

Any ideas? Or I have to do it by brute force?

This is slightly different from other posted question.

Comment: I think you could use `merge_asof`, but I've only barely used it myself so I'm hazy on the details. What other questions have you looked at? I'd wouldn't mind practicing and seeing if I can cobble something together.

Comment: Please make a [mre] including minimal example data and desired output. You should use `random.seed` so that we have the same numbers and can test possible solutions. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: It has nothing to do with date index being continuous on the days. It would still fail if you don't drop some dates in this example. It's because if you use `freq='M'`, you'll have several dates all map into one month bucket; and Pandas wouldn't know which value to pick for a given index value on assignment.

Comment: So pandas cannot shift by month in shift function?

Comment: I think I found a solution (not using `merge_asof` btw), but I want to see the desired output to be sure.

Comment: Is it possible for you to please post sample output results so we can understand the question.